# Does c++ provide any inbuilt class that gives same support as threadLocal in java?

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, thread-safety

Does c++ provide any inbuilt class similar features as threadLocal in java?
In precise :Can i declare class member variable to be thread local storage but not static ?

Comment: You mean like the `thread_local` [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)?

Comment: but  isn't it thread_local can only be static in a class?

Comment: Your edit makes this question very different. And no, you can't use `thread_local` on non-static member variables.

Comment: thanks @Someprogrammerdude  , It seems to ask much but i have a class in java to convert to similar c++  class and java class had ThreadLocal<long> public  member . i am planning to convert it to an long[no of threads] ,But can you share any other suggestion?

Comment: that class Object is shared among multiple threads?

Comment: Instead of having the threads share a single object of your class, perhaps create one object per thread? There's no "one single way" to solve problems in C++, and without knowing use-case and what problem you're trying to solve, it's impossible to do anything but guess and speculate.